# How to get Auth Token of Azure to create azure resources programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, authorization

I want to create azure resources but I am having an issue while generating the token credential for creating such resources.

The following is the way to create azure postgres SQL but I need to Pass the `credentials`
But I don't know how to generate that token programitaillcay.
I need help for this.

```
const msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
const PostgreSQLManagementClient = require('azure-arm-postgresql');

const subscriptionID = '<subscription id>';
const resourceGroup = '<resource group name>';
const serverName = '<server name>'; // must be globally unique

msRestAzure.interactiveLogin().then((credentials) => {
  let client = new PostgreSQLManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionID);
  return client.servers.createOrUpdate(resourceGroup, serverName, {
    location: 'eastus',
    properties: {
      createMode: 'Default',
      administratorLogin: 'postgres',
      administratorLoginPassword: 'F00Bar!!'
    }
  });
}).then((server) => {
  console.log('Server:');
  console.dir(server, {depth: null, colors: true});
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('An error ocurred');
  console.dir(err, {depth: null, colors: true});
});
```

Does anyone know how to generate it? and using what?  It's a signed token I guess using Client Id and tenant ID But how to generate it.

There's no documentation provided to generate it programitially. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interactiveLogin()` will provide a link and a code that will allow the user to authenticate from a browser.

When using the Node.js SDK programmatically, there are **2** methods.

1)You could use your **username and password** to authenticate with the API using your Azure account. It's **not recommended** because it requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and carries risks which are not present in other flows.

```
const Azure = require('azure');
const MsRest = require('ms-rest-azure');

MsRest.loginWithUsernamePassword(process.env.AZURE_USERNAME, process.env.AZURE_PASSWORD, (err, credentials) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  let client = new PostgreSQLManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionID);

  // ...
});
```

2)You may want to use **service principal authentication** rather than providing your account credentials. It is based on service principal without user account. First, [create service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal) in Azure portal.

```
const Azure = require('azure');
const MsRest = require('ms-rest-azure');

MsRest.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(
  'clientId/appId',
  'client-secret',
  'tenantId',
  (err, credentials) => {
    if (err) throw err

    let client = new PostgreSQLManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionID);

    // ...
  }
);
```

For more detail about JavaScript authentication samples using ms-rest-azure library, see [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/Documentation/Authentication.md).

---

**Update:**

If using service principal, try to add Azure OSSRDBMS Database application permission. Navigate to Azure AD > your app > API permission. And remember to grant admin consent for your tenant.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as an answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: For Tenant ID and Client ID where I have to generate it? and what Permissions I have to provide? Any Idea or reference for that

Comment: I get this error ```'The client \'664db141-8d06-434c-9e1a-xxxxxxxx\' with object id \'xxxxxx-8d06-434c-9e1a-aa10f3d1ca47\' does not have authorization to perform action \'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/write\' over scope \'/subscriptions/881c6f2d-c289-46c3-a7df-46db06b0de4a/resourcegroups/testrg8410\' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.' ```

Comment: Any idea fir this

Comment: Hi, @MontyPererra. Please see the update in my reply. It shows you the required permission. `Tenant ID` and `Client ID` are in the Overview of your app(service principal).